# Google Sheets Filtered View prevents app script to get correct cell by getRow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have completely the same problem as described and not answered here [google script getRow function gives different results based on filter view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61568634/google-script-getrow-function-gives-different-results-based-on-filter-view)

Here is the link to [Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BOlw3uqHTzkCEqUNek149sXjG1LLib2qgxSAv-t4ZkY/edit?usp=sharing)  modelling situation in my real file.
Sheet Movement is where data is entered, sheet History is where some rows are copied. Script copyToHistory() takes active cell and copies data from row of active cell to free row on sheet History.
Here is code

```
    function copyToHistory() {
  
  var sheetMovement = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rngCurrent = sheetMovement.getCurrentCell();
  var adr = rngCurrent.getA1Notation();
  var column = adr.substr(0,1);
  var row = adr.substr(1,  adr.length - 1);
  
  var sheetHistory = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("History");
  var lastRow  = sheetHistory.getLastRow() + 1;
  
  sheetMovement.getRange("A" + row + ":F" + row).copyTo(sheetHistory.getRange("B" + lastRow + ":G" + lastRow));
  
}
```

When no filtered view applyed all works correctly, but as soon as filtered view applied script copies different row than active cell row. It copies row with number from original unfiltered row !! It not depends on the way name of range is provided (A1 notation, row and column).
If I just activate range with given row number with filtered view applied it select correct row number.

Please help to resolve the problem and explain how to copy range from filtered sheet correctly.

Comment: Is this all your code? I don't see a doGet, or any trigger for that matter

Comment: Also, did you read the comments on the question you linked? They had some good suggestions there

Comment: @Baby_Boy, this code is just example of the problem. The trigger is button click which calls the code i showed.
I read comments of previous questions but unfortunatly couldn't get helpfull info for me.